# MacBook Pro trackpad goes erratic when paper touches it

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

Whenever I set a piece of paper or a notebook with paper over my trackpad, it begins to act erratically for hours at a time. By erratic, I mean the mouse jumps around the screen and sometimes even clicks / right-clicks. This has been happening for several years (my MBP is from 2010, late-fall 15" i7).

I've never bothered to take it in, because it usually goes away. It also helps if I vigorously wipe it with a dry cloth.

Does anyone know the cause of this? Is there some type of oil on paper that could be the culprit?

Answer (score 1):

The oils in your skin and lotion can sometimes have an effect on your trackpad. The best way to clean it is with a damp, clean, lint-free cloth. If that does not work I would try an SMC reset (http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht3964) and a PRAM reset (http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14222)